# RegEx to extract characters in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extract a set of characters in of a string.  I plan on usng the RegEx.Match method (c#) but I am unclear about the RegEx pattern to use.  I want to extract a pattern where it starts with // and ends with ...

Then length needs to be variable inside the matched string but the start and end characters will always be the same.  In DOS, I would have done something like the following:

//*...

but I know this is not the correct syntax for RegEx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with pattern

```
"//.*?\.\.\."
```

or

```
"//.*?\.{3}"
```

Some codes

```
string data = @"some codes //to double check...
another codes //done...
//to do...";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(data, @"//(.*?)\.\.\.");
foreach (Match m in matches) {
    print(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

results

```
to double check
done
to do
```

Comment: those will still match "abc//test...test" tho